# Session in Spring Rest

Tags: spring-boot, servlets, spring-rest

Hello i have a problem with session in spring rest i got everytime null in my session, this is my class

```
        @GetMapping("/shoppingCart/addProduct/{productId}")
    public ResponseEntity<Cart> addProductToCart(@PathVariable("productId") Long productId,HttpServletRequest  request) throws AppException {
        Product product = productService.getProduct(productId);

        Cart cart= (Cart) request.getSession().getAttribute("myCart");

        // If null, create it.
        if (cart == null) {
            cart = new Cart();
            request.getSession().setAttribute("myCart", cart);
        }

        cart.addProduct(product, 1);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(cart,HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }

    @GetMapping("/shoppingCart")
    public ResponseEntity<Cart> shoppingCart(HttpServletRequest  request) {
     cart = (Cart) request.getSession().getAttribute("myCart");
     return new ResponseEntity<>(cart,HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
```

this line `request.getSession().getAttribute("myCart")` returns `null`, and also when i add a product in my cart it saves in session for the first time after which when ever i try to  add another product, my session is empty.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

RestFul services are inherently designed to be stateless, hence you should not be making use of session in a Rest API in the first place. But if you are somehow required to make use of the session as per you business logic then you should make use of Spring MVC instead of REST i.e. you should use `@Controller` annotation in the class and not `@RestController`.

Comment: Thank you Dhananjay Gupta, but i create a store with spring and react and i want save my cart in session instead of session chrome.thats why